# Connect C# windows application to web based Sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have developed c# windows application which is currently working fine with lan based remote sql server using servers IP address. Now i want to host my Sql sever on web. I have hosted my database on web with the help of 'myLittleAdmin for Sql Server'. But i unable to access data from web based sql serve. My connection string is as follow -

**connectionString="Data Source= *servers ip address*;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog= *database_name* ;Integrated Security=False;User Id= *uid* ;Password= *pass* ;Trusted_Connection=true;"**

Additional Detail:

.Net Framework - 4.0

Sqlserver - 2008

Just tell me what kind of changes i should do in connection string? Or what else changes or settings i should do?

If anyone have solution please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: not need to specify of newwork dll Network Library=DBMSSOCN

Comment: Do you get an error trying to connect?  If so, what is the error message?  By the way, if you're specifying a user name and password, you are not using a trusted connection or integrated security, so you can drop that part of the connection string as well.  Also book this site [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) - its quite useful.

Comment: Also see [Connect via an IP address](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/connect-via-an-ip-address/)

Comment: Usually such problems result from firewall settings and SQL Server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The following example (passwords and servers changed) connects from anywhere to a database located on RDS within AWS, to give you an example. If you get a timeout, what is perfectly possible is that the port is blocked. So you need to make sure that you can access the database server from your web server and possibly also from your local machine. The latter can be tested by accessing the remote database from SQL Management Studio.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MainEntities" connectionString="provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=prod-xyz-db.cn56cbq5dgvl.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;initial catalog=MAIN;integrated security=False;persist security info=True;user id=main_user;password=asdfsdaiwerier;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I strongly discourage opening the database server to the world, even with a strong password. If nothing else, allow connections only from well known gateways, such as a VPN server. This is how we're working right now; if we're not in the VPN, we cannot access the databases from local machines.